# Android Sqlite failed to open database (not an error)

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, getwritabledatabase

I am currently programming an Android app where I have to use a SQLite database. At some point it happens that the database (with data stored in it) cannot be opened anymore and the app crashes and I cannot open it up again. When I reinstall the app it works just fine again. I am using an SqliteOpenHelper.

Logcat:

```
    Failed to open database '/data/data/jonas.examinationscheduler.com.examinationscheduler/KlasseLocal'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeRegisterLocalizedCollators(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:359)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:216)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:571)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
    at jonas.examinationscheduler.com.examinationscheduler.SchulenBaseHandler.getAllKlassen(SchulenBaseHandler.java:74)
    at jonas.examinationscheduler.com.examinationscheduler.PlaeneFragment.getAllePlaene(PlaeneFragment.java:87)
    at jonas.examinationscheduler.com.examinationscheduler.PlaeneFragment.onCreateView(PlaeneFragment.java:41)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
```

Where the error gets thrown (In my SqliteOpenHelper class):

```
public List<KlasseLocal> getAllKlassen(){
    List<KlasseLocal> klassenListe = new ArrayList<KlasseLocal>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_KLASSEN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); //The error gets Thrown here
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            KlasseLocal klasse = new KlasseLocal();
            klasse.setNummer(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            klasse.setSchule(cursor.getString(1));
            klasse.setKlasse(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding klasse to list
            klassenListe.add(klasse);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    // return contact list
    return klassenListe;
}
```

How I call the method:

```
List<KlasseLocal> list = new SchulenBaseHandler(getContext()).getAllKlassen();
```

Comment: it seems to be the problem of synchronization, you are opening DB connection every time you call getALlKlassen() method but where are you closing it ?? db.close() should be called and move getWritableDatabase into synchronize method

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am now closing the SqliteHelper and the SqliteDatabase object after every use but the error is still there. And what do you mean with a synchronize method?

Comment: I mean called getWritableDatabase() only once put it inside method like public void syncronize openDataBase() { SQLiteDatabase dp = getWritableDatabase() }

Comment: Thank you, I will try it